# converting the nvarchar value '2.17E+16' to data type int and The conversion of the nvarchar value '21700000001382594' overflowed an int column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have issues deleting data
I created the following using TSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[google] (
[ad] [varchar](255) NULL,
[ad_id] [varchar](30) NULL ) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[gmap] (
[ad] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
[ad_id] [nvarchar](200) NULL) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

create view [dbo].[v_google] as 
select a.[ad], a.[ad_id]
from [dbo].[google] a
left join [dbo].[gmap] b on a.[ad_id] = b.[ad_id]
GO
```

I inserted the data into the tables. When I tried to delete data with TSQL below:

```
delete b 
from [dbo].[v_google] a
join [dbo].[google] b on a.[ad] = b.[ad]
where a.ad is null
```

I get error message:

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 45
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '2.17E+16' to data type int.
Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Line 45
The conversion of the nvarchar value '21700000001382594' overflowed an int column.
```

I've looked at the solutions regarding the error message but the TSQL used are too advance for me and didn't understand it, since I'm a new learner in SQL SERVER.

Comment: None of the data types in your sample code are integers, nor do you have any arithmetic-only operators.  I don't see how this code could be generating that error.

Comment: Do you have any triggers on your tables?

Comment: @Gareth there are no triggers on the tables

Comment: The queries you have in your questions, do not lead to those errors. You obviously are testing with different queries.

Comment: Upon further inspection, the delete query you have in your question would never even delete a row, you have the join predicate `a.[ad] = b.[ad]`, then later filter with `a.ad is null` - any row where `a.ad` is null, would be removed by the inner join on this column (since null does not equal anything), so nothing would be deleted. [Example on DBFiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=532d47017d649ce59857d87b7ec419ac)

Comment: @GarethD - Thanks. I used SQL server 2012 with your examples and it worked but SQL SERVER 2017 but still having the issue. I think I will still to 2012 for practice and demo purposes because I'm still learning. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an implicit cast into INT in one of the members of the ON clause of the join. I would try to change the ON clause by casting the two members as NVARCHAR. Like this (I assume NVARCHAR(255) is long enough, you can try also BIGINT it you only have large numbers, it will make the query run faster):

```
join [dbo].[google] b on CAST (a.[ad] AS NVARCHAR(255)) = CAST (b.[ad] AS NVARCHAR(255))
```

SQL server makes implicit casts into INT if there are only integers in the data set. Then when SQL server compare the two columns in JOIN, it tries to cast the two sides of the ON in the same type (in that case INT). That's why you have a convert to INT error even if you don't explicitly try to convert to INT.